# Action deployed to Production but not accessible to users

Tags: actions-on-google

My action was approved to Production and is now fully deployed but it is still not accessible.

When users try to talk to it Google Assistant just shows an empty screen instead of running my action.

I already tried to reach out to Google Assistant support via https://support.google.com/actions-console/contact/support but they told me they don't handle technical subjects and everything seems OK on their side. =[

Below are some evidences:

The production deploy approved and already rolled out:
[image: deploy approved and rolled out]

Empty action after invoking my action in production:
[image: empty action]

Has anyone ever seen this kind of behavior?

Any clue or tip at all?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Action's response is returning an "empty" content string for the chat bubble - I can reproduce it with following response with a whitespace in the "text" property (but doesn't work with a completely empty value):

```
{
    "prompt": {
        "firstSimple": {
            "speech": "<speak><s>bla, bla, bla</s></speak>",
            "text": " "
        }
    }
}
```

Do you hear any audio output?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of places to start looking into where the problem might be:

- Check the logs for your webhook. See if you're getting the requests at all or if there is a delay in you getting the message.
- Similarly, check the healthcheck stats from Google. See if there is a high latency or a large number of failed requests.
- If your webhook isn't being called at this stage, check the Google Cloud Logging for your Action to see what *it* thinks is going on.
- Make sure your responses are valid. Depending on your logic - you may be sending back nothing.
- Your example showed this on a mobile device, which could be part of the problem

  - Does it respond the same way if it is invoked on a smart speaker or smart display?
  - Did you test it using the mobile profile in the simulator?
  - Does it respond differently if you invoke it via voice vs via the keyboard?